# Drop down arrows are not showing

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I am not getting required output of drop down menu of two arrows. I am getting only one arrow. I am using form. I wrote the following code. Can anyone help please.

```
<form action="">
  <select name="length">
    
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "two arrows"? Also how is this related to Python?

Comment: I mean the dropdown option (up and down). I am using Django framework using Python

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is a question concerning html, not python.

To get a number incrementor/decrementor, I would suggest using the [input tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp) rather than select. This can be configured to suit your needs:

```html
<input type="number" min="30" max="50" value="42">
```